# Is it possible to make a transaction with no transaction fee?

Tags: transaction-fees

Is it possible to make a transaction with no transaction fee? Is it possible to pay more fee to prioritize your transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to make a transaction with no transaction fee?

As Raghav Sood noted in a comment, transactions with no transaction fee are not transmitted by standard Bitcoin nodes - so your zero-fee transaction normally won't reach a miner. In theory you could make some special arrangement with a miner but it's hard to see why they would want to do that.

> Is it possible to pay more fee to prioritize your transaction?

Choosing a higher initial fee tends to result in quicker confirmation. If your wallet supports [Replace By Fee (RBF)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Replace_by_fee) you can use that subsequently to improve the likelihood of a quicker confirmation.

Comment: Standard nodes will not broadcast 0 fee transactions, so you likely won't be able to reach a miner at all, unless you have some special path to them

Comment: How do you choose a higher fee incase of a paper wallet?